# Deploying React native app with Django API on AWS and playstore

Tags: android, django, amazon-web-services, react-native, deployment

I'm new to development. I have created a react native expo apps that uses django API.
So to run app I have to do two things.

1. `Python manage.py runserver`
2. `npm run Android`
   I'm able to run my app locally. **My End goal is to Deploy it on Play Store.**

I'm not sure how this works. I feel I will be requiring some server that is running continuously and have an ip address. AWS can be one.

**I'm looking forward for more insights on How this deployment can be done and steps involved in it?** Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: This question may be too broad. I understand that you're new to development, but there's no single answer as to how to deploy what you've described, and the steps involved are numerous and non-exhaustive depending on what your web service needs to do.